# Android vibrate is deprecated. How to use VibrationEffect in Android>= API 26?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-8.0-oreo, android-vibration

I am using Android's `VIBRATOR_SERVICE` to give a haptic feedback for a button touch.

```
 ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(300);
```

Android Studio give me warning that method `vibrate(interval)` is deprecated I should use `VibrationEffect` for API>23.

So I used`VibrationEffect`'s method `createOneShot` which takes 2 params: interval, and amplitude. 
[image]

I tried searching for it but got no clue about what to pass as `amplitude`, anybody got any idea about how to use it?

**Update Added code**

```
// Vibrate for 150 milliseconds
private void shakeItBaby() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(150,10));
    } else {
        ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(150);
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code in the question itself. Don't include the screenshots

Comment: int: The strength of the vibration. This must be a value between 1 and 255, or DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE. (according to documentation)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/VibrationEffect.html#createOneShot(long,%20int)

Comment: I added the screen shot to show method params.

Comment: added code if you want to see

Comment: `shakeItBaby` PMPL

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74376147/2212458 for an updated answer taking into account changes in both SDK 26 and 31.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Amplitude is an int value. Its The strength of the vibration. This must be a value between 1 and 255, or `DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE` which is -1.

You can use it as `VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE`

More details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/VibrationEffect.html)

Comment: Note that in Xamarin Forms this is defined as `VibrationEffect.DefaultAmplitude`

Answer (score 38):

with kotlin

```
private fun vibrate(){
    val vibrator = context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
         vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(200, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE))
    } else {
         vibrator.vibrate(200)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use this for haptic feedback (vibration):

```
view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);
```

There are other constants available in `HapticFeedbackConstants` like `VIRTUAL_KEY`, `KEYBOARD_TAP` ...

Comment: For most uses, this should be the correct one as is the simplest (and native) implementation so far.

Answer (score 12):

### Updated for Kotlin

```
// Vibrates the device for 100 milliseconds.
fun vibrateDevice(context: Context) {
    val vibrator = getSystemService(context, Vibrator::class.java)
    vibrator?.let {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            it.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(100, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE))
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            it.vibrate(100)
        }
    }
}
```

Call the function as following:

```
vibrateDevice(requireContext())
```

Make sure you add permission to AndroidManifest.xml as following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Note that you don't need to ask for permission at runtime for using vibration.

You need to suppress deprecation in `else` clause, because the warning is from newer SDK.

Comment: `val vibrator = context.getSystemService(Vibrator::class.java)`

Answer (score 5):

I just stumbled across this and found out that `VibrationEffect.createWaveform()` basically uses the same `long[]`-pattern as the old `vibrate()`.

Because of this, you can reuse your existing pattern like so (this is a Kotlin extension-function):

```
fun Context.vibrate(pattern: LongArray) {
    val vibrator =
        applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator? ?: return

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        vibrator.vibrate(
            VibrationEffect.createWaveform(pattern, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)
        )

    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        vibrator.vibrate(pattern, -1)
    }
}
```

And instead of `VibrationEffect.createOneShot()` you can use a pattern as well (e.g. `longArrayOf(0, 150)`) so no need to use different functions.

Comment: Note that pattern will work in two different ways here. `createWaveform` accepts timings and amplitudes, and vibrate accepts paired off/on timings.

Answer (score 2):

This library may help you out:
https://github.com/josephrubin/Rumble-4-Android

All you would need is
`Rumble.once(150);`

It handles the API versions for you.

Answer (score 2):

working for me `kotlin ext fun`

for the haptic effect, vibro has 5 milliseconds!! (`SHORT_HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_DURATION`)

```
fun Context.performHapticFeedback() {
    val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val vibrationEffect = VibrationEffect.createOneShot(HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_DURATION, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)
        vibrator.vibrate(vibrationEffect)
    } else {
        vibrator.vibrate(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(SHORT_HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_DURATION))
    }
}

private const val SHORT_HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_DURATION = 5L
```

usage

```
addOnItemTouchListener(ItemTouchListener { position, event ->
                if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    context.performHapticFeedback()  
                }  
            })
```

permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

good luck ✌ :))

Answer (score 1):

[image]Open **Manage NuGet Packages**

Search and Install **Xamarin.Essentials**

```
try {
 var duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
 Vibration.Vibrate(duration);
} 
 catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex){} 
 catch (Exception ex){}
```

Comment: It's already in ms . No need to convert anything: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate(long) .  Just one line of code is needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    fun setVibrationSettings(context: Context, isVibrationOn: Boolean) {
        val vibrator = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            val vibrationEffect =
                VibrationEffect.createOneShot(1000, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)
            (context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager).run {
                if (isVibrationOn) {
                    this.defaultVibrator.vibrate(vibrationEffect)
                } else {
                    this.defaultVibrator.cancel()
                }
            }
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val vibrationEffect =
                VibrationEffect.createOneShot(1000, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)
            (context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator).run {
                if (isVibrationOn) {
                    this.vibrate(vibrationEffect)
                } else {
                    this.cancel()
                }
            }
        } else {
            (context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator).run {
                if (isVibrationOn) {
                    this.vibrate(1000)
                } else {
                    this.cancel()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Code with check SDK for 31 and 26 SDK

ADD permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```