# How to enable vibration on touching every button in app

Tags: android, kotlin, vibration

In my settings menu i have used a switch when i turn it on i want every button in-app to vibrate and when i turn the switch off i want every button in-the app to not vibrate.

The following is the code i have tried so far.

```
    switch2!!.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if (switch2!!.isChecked) {
switch2!!.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);
        }
        else {
                vibrator.cancel()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

1. Using `SharedPreference` . *https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences*
2. Once you stored the key, you can use the key at the other activity/fragment.
3. At `onCreate` , you get the value from `SharedPreference`.
4. You use variable to check it first before click the button.
5. If yes, then vibrate it. Refer to this. *https://stackoverflow.com/a/52990380/9346054*

**Don't forget to declare at `AndroidManifest` as the refer above.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Example.

Here at `onCreate`

```
val vibe = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
val isVibrate = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.is_vibrate), defaultValue)
```

And then inside `onClick` button

```
    if (isVisible) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(200, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE))
        } else {
            vibrator.vibrate(200)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this permission first

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

and next you can use this fun for vibrate mobile

```
fun vibratePhone(context: Context?, milliseconds: Int) {
    val vibrator = context?.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        vibrator.vibrate(
            VibrationEffect.createOneShot(
                milliseconds,
                VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE
            )
        )
    } else {
        vibrator.vibrate(milliseconds)
    }
}
```